# How can I join 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 3 mysql tables. The first table(`tb_user`) or the parent table have columns `region_id` and `institution_id` and both can also be found from a different tables:

- `region_id`(table: `tb_region`), and
- `institution_id`(table: `tb_institutional_profile`).

How do I query it to get all the columns in `tb_user` and display names(`region_name` from `tb_region` and `institution_name` form `tb_institutional_profile`) and not `ID`s.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  t.username, 
  r.region_name, 
  i.instituation_name
FROM tb_user t
INNER JOIN tb_region r ON t.region_id = r.region_id
INNER JOIN tb_institutional_profile i ON t.institution_id = i.institution_id
```

Comment: Unknown column 't.region_id' in 'on clause'
My query:
`SELECT *, r.region_name, i.institution_name FROM tb_user INNER JOIN tb_region r ON t.region_id = r.region_id INNER JOIN tb_institutional_profile i ON t.institution_id = i.institution_id WHERE status = 'inactive' ORDER BY date_register ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0`

Comment: @JethroTamaresDoble Is there `region_id` in the table `tb_user`?

Comment: @JethroTamaresDoble You forgot to alias the table `tb_user` in the query you posted in your comment insead of `... FROM tbl_user INNER JOIN tb_region ...` add an alias to it like `... FROM tb_user t INNER JOIN tb_region r ON t.region_id = r.region_id ...`

Comment: @JethroTamaresDoble - You're welcome any time. Glad to help you :)